# How to split words in-place, within a nested list

Tags: python, replace, nested-lists

This is my code:

`abc` is a multi dimensional list

Input list: `abc = [['word1_word1.5','word2'],['word1_word1.5','word2']]`

```
for i in range(len(abc)):
    for j in range(len(abc[i])):
        if "word1_word1.5" in abc[i][j]:
                newword = abc[i][j].split("_")
                // Replace the abc[i][j] with "word1" and "word1.5"
```

Output Expected:

`abc = [['word1','word1.5','word2'],['word1','word1.5','word2']]`

Comment: FWIW, with the given sample, you can pretty much ignore `xyz` and simply split every word on `_` to reach the same result. Is that the case with your actual data too?

Comment: @usr2564301 sub-lists might be separate documents or similar

Comment: `abc` is a multi dimensional list. I tried adding 2-3 loops to do this, but they are very slow.

Comment: Sorry, there might be some words that I don't want to split by `_` @deceze

Comment: You'd be better off casting your `xyz` to a `set` and then loop `abc` and check for each element if it is in `xyz` split it

Comment: In my code, one major problem I am facing is `.copy()`. I am trying to create a temporary variable  like `abc2 = abc.copy()` but any changes in `abc2` create changes in `abc` also.

Comment: Is there any easy function to split the word into two once I find the index of the word to split. For example, Let's say, I find the word to split like `abc[i][j]`. Now how should I split this word into 2 in the same list?

Comment: You can do `abc[i][j:j+1] = abc[i][j].split("_")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this:

```
>>> abc = [['word1_word1.5', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4_word4.5'], ['word5_word5.5', 'word2', 'word3', 'word1_word1.5']]
```

Splitting each word:

```
>>> [[w.split('_') for w in l] for l in abc]
[[['word1', 'word1.5'], ['word2'], ['word3'], ['word4', 'word4.5']], [['word5', 'word5.5'], ['word2'], ['word3'], ['word1', 'word1.5']]]
```

Concatenating the sub-lists:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [list(chain.from_iterable(w.split('_') for w in l)) for l in abc]
[['word1', 'word1.5', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word4.5'], ['word5', 'word5.5', 'word2', 'word3', 'word1', 'word1.5']]
```

Splitting only if `w` appears in `xyz`:

```
>>> xyz = {'word1_word1.5', 'word5_word5.5', 'word4_word4.5'}
>>> [list(chain.from_iterable(w.split('_') if w in xyz else [w] for w in l)) for l in abc]
[['word1', 'word1.5', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word4.5'], ['word5', 'word5.5', 'word2', 'word3', 'word1', 'word1.5']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for lst in abc:
    for n in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[n] in xyz:
            wrd = lst.pop(n)
            lst += wrd.split("_")
```

This will replace words that exist in `xyz` with their split version, in-place within `abc`

Comment: A neat way of doing that without `pop`ing is using slice-assignment: `lst[n:n+1] = lst[n].split('_')`

Comment: This add the new word at the end, not at the previous index.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying to implement it

Answer (score -1):

```
for item in abc:
    for ele in item:
        if ele in xyz:
            split_word = ele.split("_")
```

This logic return you splitted words in form of list stored in `split_word`.
Now replace the original word in `abc` with `split_word`.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey, Finding the word is not my problem. How should I replace the word? That is where I am facing trouble

Comment: Hi 
Then how about this algorithm: 
1) Read the word and store its index 
2) if word needs to be replaced 
      1 - Split this word using `split' function
      2 - Remove the word using `list.remove('your_word')`
      3 - Insert these split words using `list.insert(index, element)`

Comment: How does this answer supposed to help OP? The code is pretty much the same as the code OP already has, and exactly the part he is asking about is missing here...